# Big oh / big theta proof for the following

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing, logarithms, asymptotics

Find a number $a$ with $s(n) = \Theta(a^n)$ for $s(n) = (\log_2{10})^{(n-3)}$.

I'm not quite sure how to proceed. I was having problems with another problem trying to figure out what it means to raise a logarithm to an exponent. For example, in another problem, I was trying to show that $(n * \log_2{(n+1)})^2 \le C * n^2$, but I got stuck at $n^2 * (\log_2{(n+1)})^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $a=\log_2 10$. Then $s(n)=\frac{a^n}{(\log_2 10)^3}$; can you conclude from there using the definition of $\Theta(\cdot)$?

---

Incidentally, regarding your second (embedded) question: you will not be able to find any constant $C$ such that $(n\log_2(n+1))^2 \leq Cn^2$. Indeed, $\frac{(n\log_2(n+1))^2}{n^2} = (\log_2(n+1))^2 \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty$.

Comment: Thank you. Would I be able to find one if I used $n^3$ or $n^4$ instead?

Comment: Yes (the ratio would then go to $0$, and therefore be bounded).